# default value if variable hidden PHP

Tags: php, arrays

pls help me..
im trying to input value with this code :

```
$attr_checklist = $flagTriwulan[$i] ? "hidden" : '';

 echo "<td class='basicTable padding10 textCenter' style=\"font-size:13px;\"> <center>
<input type='radio' ".$attr_checklist." name='nilaikuantitatif[<?php echo [$i]; ?>]'  
value='5'></center> 
<br>".$skala5[$i]." </br>
</td>";
```

this when im submit :

```
if(isset($_POST['cmdSubmit']))
{
    $aspek_a = $_POST['aspek_a'];
    $nilaikuantitatif = $_POST['nilaikuantitatif'];

    $multi = new MultipleIterator();
    $multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($aspek_a));
    $multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($nilaikuantitatif));


    foreach($multi as $key => $value)
    {
        list($aspek_a, $nilaikuantitatif) = $multi->key();
        list($aspek_a, $nilaikuantitatif) = $value;

        $queryInsAspek = "insert into kpi_kuantitatif 
                         (idDivisi,idDepartment,idEmployee,idPenilai,bulan,tahun
                           ,aspek, nilaikuantitatif,submitBy, inputDT)
            select".$idDivisi.",".$idDepartment.",".$idEmployee_C.",".$idEmployee.",".$bulan.",".$tahun.",'". $aspek_a."','".$nilaikuantitatif."',".$userID.", getdate()";
        $resultInsAspek = sqlsrv_query($conn, $queryInsAspek); 
                                        }
```

so, i want if hidden then the value nilaiKuantitatif becomes 0, but if not hidden the value nilaiKuantitatif becomes 5

sorry for my bad english..pls help

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh if hidden nilaikuantitatif ​​are not submitted to the database..
i want if hidden then the value nilaiKuantitatif becomes 0, but if not hidden the value nilaiKuantitatif becomes 5

Comment: Some basic debugging, before the loop have a look what `$multi` contains.  Also not sure why you set `list($aspek_a, $nilaikuantitatif)` twice with different values as they will overwrite the first set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you want the `value` in this code to be `0` in the event `$attr_checklist == "hidden"`...

```
$attr_checklist = $flagTriwulan[$i] ? "hidden" : '';

 echo "<td class='basicTable padding10 textCenter' style=\"font-size:13px;\"> <center>
<input type='radio' ".$attr_checklist." name='nilaikuantitatif[<?php echo [$i]; ?>]'  
value='5'></center> 
<br>".$skala5[$i]." </br>
</td>";
```

Change this...

```
value=`5`
```

To...

```
value='<?php echo $attr_checklist == "hidden" ? 0 : 5; ?>'
```